# How to have both fullscreen and no focus on an OpenGL window

Tags: winapi, opengl, glut

Lets say I have an OpenGL window and I call the glut function glutFullScreen(). My OpenGL window is fullscreen, this part is OK.

Any idea how to put it in background and handle all the clicks/mouse/keyboard interaction as if this specific window did not exist (but still keeping the fullscreen view) ?

Answer (score 0):

What is it exactly you try to accomplish? Do you want to render a screen sized image, but don't want the rendering being visible?

Just use Framebuffer Object (FBO) for this, which makes rendering independent of the window's visibility or size.

Comment: Imagine you take a camera to film your screen and then project the film back on a window which is in front of you. Your mouse and keyboard are still interacting with your applications on your first screen, but you are in fact looking at the film.

Then you can do whatever you want with the film you recorded, for example rotating it, applying effects on it and such.

Now, back to my concern, I want the rendering scene to be on a full screen window (and I want to see it), however, I want my mouse and keyboard not to interact with it, to interact with what is "behind" this full screen window.

Comment: @Al_th: I'm afraid this is not trivially possible. Essentially when you click on the visible portion of a window, the window manager will direct all the events to that window. Keyboard events is slightly different as in that case it's the focus that's relevant. **However** what you describe sound as you'd like to implement *window compositing*: Render the windows on the desktop using OpenGL so that you can apply all kinds of nifty effects. There are special APIs to implement compositing, which also take care about input redirection. But compositing APIs are OS dependent.

Comment: @Al_th: Compositing is far easier to implement on Linux/X11 than on Windows. Since Windows Vista there's a compositor API available, however when you use that, you've to replace the Windows Vista compositor.

Comment: Well, I don't want to do compositing (if what I read on wikipedia is true). The real deal is I want to be able to simulate a multi screen in a virtual environment by rendering applications windows on different surfaces, surfaces I can place anywhere I want and then use regular FPS game techniques to look around. At the end I'll have the occulus VR to work on as a second screen, but for now on I wanted to simulate it on my only screen. Thanks anyway

Comment: @Al_th: While this looks differently than classical compositing one would use the Compositing API for that application as well. What happens in compositing is, that every window gets moved "off" the screen. The compositor then gets each window as a separate pixmap (which it can use as texture in OpenGL) to draw it however and whereever it sees fit. I have no knowledge about using the Windows compositing API, but I have experience using the X11 Composite extension. And what you describe is perfectly feasible to do with X11 Composite and a OpenGL based compositor.

Comment: Well, then i'll throw a glance at this, definitely thanks for the input.

I'll leave people some time and then will accept your answer

Comment: @Al_th: If you want go along with the compositing method, let me know; I'd gladly offer help.